# Getting and calculating stuff through tkinter widets

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering how to calculate stuff using tkinter buttons. I'm making a simple program to calculate seconds to hours:minutes:seconds. The user inputs an integer using the entry widget on the seconds box and when they press calculate, they get the result via the converted time line. I'm confused on how to start calculating it. I know you get the integer via .get, but I'm stuck on how to do that and calculate it in a h:m:s format. This is my code so far.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *




class TimeConverterUI():


    def __init__(self):

        self.root_window = Tk()
        self.root_window.geometry('400x150')
        self.root_window.title('Seconds Converter')
        self.text()
        self.calculate_button()
        self.quit_button()
        self.root_window.wait_window()


    def text(self):

        row_label = tkinter.Label(
              master = self.root_window, text = 'Seconds: ')

        row_label.grid( row = 0, column = 0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10,
                           sticky = tkinter.W)

        secondsEntry = Entry(master = self.root_window)
        secondsEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        row_label = tkinter.Label(
              master = self.root_window, text = 'Converted Time(H:M:S): ').grid(row=1)

    def calculate_button(self):

        quit = Button(self.root_window, text = "Calculate", command = self.calculate)
        quit.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady=20,
                  sticky = tkinter.W)

    def calculate(self):

        pass

    def quit_button(self):

        quit = Button(self.root_window, text = "Quit", command = self.quit)
        quit.grid(row = 3, column = 3, columnspan = 3, pady=20,
                  sticky = tkinter.E)

    def quit(self) -> bool:

        self.root_window.destroy()
        return True





if __name__ == '__main__':

    convert=TimeConverterUI()
```

Comment: 'calculating stuff' is in no way related to TkInter widgets. This is math.

Comment: I know, but how would I get the .get() to calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

First break this code below into 2 lines if you ever want to use `row_label` later because this will return `NoneType`. You should define it first then use `.grid` on it (just like your button).

```
row_label = tkinter.Label(
              master = self.root_window, text = 'Converted Time(H:M:S): ').grid(row=1)
```

Now you can create another label to show the result. Remember to put `self.` before its name so you can use it in the `calculate` function. Also change `secondsEntry` to `self.secondsEntry` for the same reason.
Now you just use `int(self.secondsEntry.get())` in that function and do the required calculations.
 Then set the result to that result label with `.configure(text=str(result))`