# Clearing tkinter entry box after displayed result

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm calculating seconds into h:m:s format and using tkinter for it. I basically got the program done but there's an issue with it. It calculates the first result perfectly, but when I press calculate again, it concatenates to the result. How would I fix it so it clears the first result when the user wants to calculate again? I tried using self.result.delete(0,END), but that displays nothing after calculate. Here are the functions for the problem in question.

Comment: The way to clear an entry is indeed to call `self.result.delete(0, END)` (assuming you did a wildcard import). Please show a [mcve] that shows how you called it.

Comment: @BryanOakley edited the post with the full code along with the self.result.delete(0,END) in it.

Comment: why are you deleting _after_ you insert? Did it occur to you to delete the old text _before_ inserting the new?

Comment: In your `calculate` method, you should call `self.result.delete(0, END)` before `self.result.insert(0, c)`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of deleting before insert. Thanks!

Comment: Hey seems to me you got your answer for your previous question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760552/getting-and-calculating-stuff-through-tkinter-widets/45761578#45761578).  Accept an answer if it helped you... or comment to let people know where you had problem with it. This site doesn't work one sided.

Comment: Why was the code removed?

Answer (score 0):

The below demonstrates how you can clear an `entry` widget using a `button`:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.entry = Entry(self.root)
        self.button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=self.command)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.button.pack()
    def command(self):
        self.entry.delete(0, END)

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The code is pretty self explanatory, `self.entry.delete(0, END)` will simply remove the text in the entry from position '0' to position '`END`'.

Answer (score 0):

The way you would do this is with `textbox.delete(0, END)`.  END (or “end”) corresponds to the position just after the last character in the entry widget. The range (0, END) corresponds to all characters in the widget